# Black stains/pixels render

Tags: rendering, texturing

I am having an issue with a rendering. I am trying to render a outside architecture scene with a sky texture (nishita)
For some reasons, there are some black stains/pixel in some random areas of the render...

I'm using blender 2.90.1

Here is the file :
[image]

Any thought ? :D

[image]

Thanks

Valentin

Comment: What render engine are you using? What are your render settings? (Especially your shadow and ambient occlusion settings)

Comment: Hi ! I am rendering in cycles

Comment: at 400 samples
Ambiant occlusion factor .1 and distance 10

Comment: Hi @valentin :) Please add new information to your question as an [edit] rather than as comments so that other users will see them in the text of your question. I would suggest adding much more info so that your question is more clear as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful with the musgrave texture. Its values are not constrained to the [0...1] range, which can result in negative values. The roughness is not supposed to get negative values, thus the black artifacts.

An easy fix is to add a clamp node, which will constrain the result between 0 and 1.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! That was a tricky one !

Comment: Hi! If that answer did help to solve your issue, please consider to accept and upvote the ansewer @valentin How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour