# Crumpled cloth/paper-like black artefacts on render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to get rid of these black artefacts that looks like crumpled paper.

From my kitchen scene below, it's mostly on the lower part of the render and you can find most of it at the right.

[image]

I have the nishita sky texture on[image]

And these are my render settings:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Btw the lower right white cube is just a simple mesh—a white cube with the default material..

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you are using a Musgrave-noise as input for a bump-node for your surfaces?
If so, you should add a "Clamp"-node in between, as Musgrave can deliver values outside the expected bounds.

(There used to be a great answer with this info some months ago, but I couldn't find it any more to link it here, sorry...)

Comment: That rang a bell :) is it possible you're talking about this question ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/200893/86891

Comment: Exactly that's what I meant :-)